# Decode and encode Windows 10 ImagesRootPIDL with C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

Windows stores the slideshow directory or images root in a slideshow.ini file located here:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini`

Unfortunately, Windows encodes the images root path.

```
[Slideshow]
ImagesRootPIDL=BFAFA8BUg/E0gouOpBhoYjAArADMdqDAuAI160KJpVKMFhZ4rKQ+BpHqmAQAAYCAv7bEAAAAgckY+qzmVHQNq78JeCc1BQ8j2nI6DXdAUAQ8AEDAAAAAAECU7MGEAcVQMxEUB5XMAAgRAkAAEAw7+GCUSLWIQtzYuAAAAcOFFAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQY6IBAXBQYAwGAsBAcAEGAwBQZAIHAzBAAAgBATCAAAcCAv7bhAAAAxMFUTdbnu+fjc8/QByIhApzoz1SaAAAAkBAAAAwHAAAAsAAAAcHApBgbAQGAvBwdAMHAuAQaA0GAtBQZAIHAzBQaAYHAlBwYA8GAuBAdAIHAvBAbAAHAhBgbAUGAsBwXAMGA3BQNA4GAxAAaAIDA0BAeAkHAlBwdAkHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgBAAAA
```

How to decode and encode a directory path into a Windows compatible encrypted PIDL?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found this [Decode() method](https://github.com/bimal-b/Binger/blob/master/Binger/NativeMethods.cs#L210) but it returns an empty string with the imagesRoot provided in my question post.

Comment: Updated link for that [Decode method](https://github.com/bimal-b/Binger/blob/169939ce7c6ccfe3f179ce59e20da280c96d0bd4/Binger/Slideshow/Pidl.cs#L181) I can confirm it does not work and gives empty string for me as well